# How to avoid part of 13 column in next page i want to get every page has full value without split into next page?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

[image: How to avoid part of 13 column in next page i want to get every page has full value without split into next page?]

How to avoid part of 13 column in next page i want to get every page has full value without split into next page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the Split Type for the Detail band to `Prevent` or `Immediate`. I cannot remember off the top of my head which one it is, but it is one of those. I think it is `Immediate`, and it should cause it to put a page break right after the last row that can completely fit.